# Parse XLSX into JSON

Tags: excel, npm, xlsx, js-xlsx

I am trying to parse Excel content into JSON using the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm module, however it doesn't return any content.

Why don't I find anything inside `workbook.Sheets`?

**Example:**

```js
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.body.content+'.xlsx');

var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

var ws = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]];

console.log(ws) //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You should recode line 3 like down below.

`var ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);`